# Django form field widget becomes hidden

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-widget

Model field links as `foreign_key` to another model which has big amount of entries.

I decided to replace default select for `foreign_keys` with simple link.

And it works grate besides the fact that field becomes hidden!

[image: img]

What should I do to avoid that?

admin.py

```
class SeriesAdmin(ModelLinkAdminFields, admin.ModelAdmin):
    modellink = ['video',]
```

wdiget_file.py

```
class ModelLinkWidget(forms.HiddenInput):

    def __init__(self, admin_site, original_object):
        self.admin_site = admin_site
        self.original_object = original_object
        super(ModelLinkWidget,self).__init__()


    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if self.original_object is not None:
            change_url = urlresolvers.reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % 
                                              (type(self.original_object)._meta.app_label, 
                                               type(self.original_object)._meta.object_name.lower()),
                                              args=(self.original_object.id,))
            return mark_safe('<a id="%s" name="{name}" href="%s">%s</a>' % 
                             (attrs['id'], change_url , escape(self.original_object)))
        else:
            return None

class ModelLinkAdminFields(object):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):

        form = super(ModelLinkAdminFields, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

        if hasattr(self, 'modellink'):
            for field_name in self.modellink:
                if field_name in form.base_fields:
                    form.base_fields[field_name].widget = ModelLinkWidget(self.admin_site, getattr(obj, field_name, ''))
        return form
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your widget overrides `forms.HiddenInput`

You should use the correct widget, I presume this should be [`Select`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#select) but there are [other options available](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#built-in-widgets)